# how to write hql join query

Tags: mysql, hql

I'm new from HQL any one Please tell me how to write this Query in HQL.

**My SQL Method is**

```
public Integer validateEditDate(int id, String date);
```

**My SQL Query is**

```
SELECT 
count(a.activity_task_id)
FROM activity_task_details AS a
JOIN milestone_activity_details AS b
    ON a.milestone_activity_id =  b.milestone_activity_id
WHERE a.milestone_activity_id = 17
    AND DATE(a.task_end_date) > '20161229';
```

Where `id` and `date` is dynamic

Please convert this sql query in Hql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a SQL query in HQL you must define, as first, classes about db table mapping.

You have these two tables:

`activity_task_details
 milestone_activity_details`

So you must have two classes, as follow:

`ActivityTaskDetails
MilestoneActivityDetails`

So, you must map your fields as properties. Suppose you have done this, your query will became:

```
SELECT 
count(a.activity_task_id)
FROM ActivityTaskDetails a, MilestoneActivityDetails b
WHERE a.milestone_activity_id =  b.milestone_activity_id
AND a.milestone_activity_id = :paramId
AND a.task_end_date > :paramDate;
```

Pay attention, if possible, your `task_end_date` in class `ActivityTaskDetails` declare as `date`

To execute your query:

```
String hql = "Your HQL query write upper";
Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
q.setString("paramId", id);
q.setDate("paramDate", date);
q.list();
```

`session` is a variable to get session factory object

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer , but i got before that, thank u very much again..

Comment: @hardikshah: Because you're newbie of SO, if you want you can accept my answer (if accomplish your goal)